# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.tnbdev.ulam.model.Region.getSubregionMark()' on a null object reference

Tags: android

I am build the navigation view using fragment method. in this fragment i create some method to show the view, such as spinner when click value in spinner, it will display in the recycle view. but the problem is in the adapter is show null object references.

```java
public class LRPFragment extends Fragment {

    private String mInstituteLocation = "";
    private Spinner sp;

    DatabaseReference db;
    FirebaseHelper helper;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    LRPAdapter adapter;
    List<Region> routesList;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        helper=new FirebaseHelper(db);
        View RootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lrp, container, false);

        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

        recyclerView = RootView.findViewById(R.id.rv_rec_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);

        sp = (Spinner) RootView.findViewById(R.id.subreg);

        loadRoute("Region");


        return RootView;
    }

    private void loadRoute(final String referenceKey){

        db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(referenceKey);
        db.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                final List<String> subregionMark = new ArrayList<>();
                subregionMark.add(0, "Choose Subregion");

                for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1: snapshot.getChildren()){
                        subregionMark.add(dataSnapshot1.child("subregionMark").getValue(Region.class).getSubregionMark());//null object references on getSubregionMark
                    }
                }
                ArrayAdapter <String> subAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, subregionMark);
                subAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                sp.setAdapter(subAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        getActivity().setTitle("Menu LRPFragment");


    }
}
```

This is constructor

```java
public class Region {

    String name;
    String start;
    String end;
    String distance;
    String regionMark;
    String subregionMark;

    public String getStart() {
        return start;
    }

    public void setStart(String start) {
        this.start = start;
    }

    public String getEnd() {
        return end;
    }

    public void setEnd(String end) {
        this.end = end;
    }

    public String getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }

    public void setDistance(String distance) {
        this.distance = distance;
    }

    public String getSubregionMark() {
        return subregionMark;
    }

    public void setSubregionMark(String subregionMark) {
        this.subregionMark = subregionMark;
    }


    public Region() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getRegionMark() {
        return regionMark;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setRegionMark(String regionMark) {
        this.regionMark = regionMark;
    }
```

This is layout where i call fragment

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/rel"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/tvreg"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="-57dp"
            android:text="LRP"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="25dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvreg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="23dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/regionMark"
            android:text="REGION" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/regionMark"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="13dp"
            android:contextClickable="true"
            android:entries="@array/regionMark"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="113dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvreg"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/subreg"
            android:text="SUBREGION" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/subreg"
            android:layout_width="230dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/regionMark"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/or"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="OR"
            android:layout_below="@+id/subreg"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

        <SearchView
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/or"
            android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
            android:inputType="textAutoComplete|textAutoCorrect"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"

            >

            <requestFocus />
        </SearchView>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/filterTCBtn"
            android:text="Filter"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"/>

    </RelativeLayout>


    <TextView
        android:layout_below="@+id/rel"
        android:id="@+id/route_view_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Route View"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_rec_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/route_view_menu"
        android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"
        android:padding="3dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[This is myfirebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3nVA.png)

Comment: Seems like `dataSnapshot1.child("subregionMark").getValue(Region.class)` returning `null`. Debug it and Fix it .

Comment: how can i debug it? seem i don see the problem. in my firebase it has data

Comment: Okay.  Add a screen shot of your firebase tree containing data with question.

Comment: im done add screenshot.

Comment: I think  it should be `dataSnapshot1.getValue(Region.class).getSubregionMark()`

Comment: alright thanks. it solve my problem.